# BOOST regex - no prototype for u32regex_replace() with callback function

Tags: c++, regex, boost, utf-8, mfc

Am using `Boost Regex v1.56 from VS2010 platform/C++/Mfc`.

I'm converting some C++ ANSI to Unicode.
I was using the `regex_replace()` with a functor callback (*`Formatter fmt`*).

I can find no callback counterpart using `u32regex_replace()`.
There doesn't seem to exist a like template in `icu.hpp`.

I'd rather not have to use a `u32regex_search()` to simulate a replacement. 
Anybody know if there exists a callback capability for the u32 counterpart
of `regex_replace`?

Note - Boost regex docs state this on the u32 equivalents:

> For each regex_replace algorithm defined by `<boost/regex.hpp>`, then `<boost/regex/icu.hpp>` defines an overloaded algorithm that takes the same arguments, but which is called `u32regex_replace`, and which will accept UTF-8, UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded data, as well as an ICU UnicodeString as input. The input sequence and the format string specifier passed to the algorithm, can be encoded independently (for example one can be UTF-8, the other in UTF-16), but the result string / output iterator argument must use the same character encoding as the text being searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to answer my own question with a work around.
Kind of figured no callback for `u32regex_replace` was available since I couldn't find it.

After looking at the normal regex_replace and the u32 stuff in icu.cpp,
Its apparent, he uses `regex_iterator` for just about everything.

So, this almost would duplicate a regex_replace with a *`Formatter fmt`*
functor.

```
 // Ficticous formatter string.
 std::wstring sReplace = _T( "$1$2" );

 // Callback Functor.
 std::wstring Callback( const boost::wsmatch m )
 {
    // Do stuff here, thats why its a callbck !! 
    return m.format( sReplace );
 }

 // ------------------------------------------

 // Ficticous test regex
 boost::u32regex Regex = make_u32regex( _T("(?<=(\\w))(?=(\\w))") ));

 // Create a u32regex_iterator via make_u32regex_iterator
 // 
 boost::u32regex_iterator<std::wstring::const_iterator>
    i(boost::make_u32regex_iterator( sInput, Regex)), j;

 // Ficticous input string.
 std::wstring sInput = _T( "This is a sentence"" );

 // Maintain a last iterator to use for the ending.
 std::wstring::const_iterator last = sInput.begin();

 // Clear the output string
 sOutput = _T("");

 // Do global replace with callback.
 while(i != j)
 {
    sOutput.append( (*i).prefix() );      // append last match to here
    sOutput.append( Callback( (*i) ) ) ;  // append callback string
    last = (*i)[0].second;                // save to 'last' the end of this match
    ++i;
 }

 // Append any trailing text.
 sOutput.append( last, stext.end() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Version control to the rescue!

A quick `git blame` on the `HEAD` version of [`regex_replace.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/regex/blame/master/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_replace.hpp) shows that the template `Formatter` was added with commit [`ae79f29`](https://github.com/boostorg/regex/commit/ae79f29895cc867aebf889d010cd0470401356a6) on December 8, 2009, i.e. was new with Boost version 1.42.

The template definitions of `u32regex_replace` in [`icu.hpp`](https://github.com/boostorg/regex/blame/master/include/boost/regex/icu.hpp) on the other hand, have not been changed since commit [`71a0e02`](https://github.com/boostorg/regex/commit/71a0e020e2c0982ccc04318765be189457ea8fa1) from January 13, 2005, i.e. v.1.33.

Based on this we have to conclude that the support for function objects as well as strings when formatting never made it into the u32 counterpart functions, and you are unfortunately out of luck at this point in time.

boost.org provides [this information](http://www.boost.org/development/bugs.html) about reporting and fixing bugs.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I'm going to check that out shortly. thanks again!

Comment: @sln Great! If my sources seem "credible and/or official" enough for you, I'd appreciate an accept on this one ;)